# Error on trying to ssh to a prgmr box when using PuTTY like utility KiTTY

Tags: ssh, authentication, kerberos, putty, gssapi

I recently got a box on prgmr. Excited, I tried to login using my username password in [KiTTY](http://kitty.9bis.com/) (which is basically an improved PuTTY) and got the following error, shown in the screenshot.

Now, I can connect fine when using a Linux terminal. The authentication in this case is a little different because, after successful authentication it shows a menu with a number of options that you can select to start/stop/restart the server etc.

I googled a little and came to know that its something to do with Kerberos and authentication and I need to enable some settings in the SSH > Auth section of KiTTY. I tried enabling/disabling and tried everything in general, but still getting this error.

[image]

[image: GSSAPI Settings in KiTTY]

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Which authentication method is your server using: password or public key? Please give us the output when you connect from Linux?

Comment: its using public key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't specified the private key for authentication:

[image]